# Xamarin- iOS Bluetooth App disconect immediately

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, core-bluetooth, ios7.1, xamarin-studio

today i installed new updates from Xamarin studio and  after installing new updates my ios bluetooth app stops working. When the app try to connect to the bluetooth device, it disconnects immediately by throwing following exception message:Disconnection Error:

Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=10 "The connection has failed unexpectedly." UserInfo=0x15863200 {NSLocalizedDescription=The connection has failed unexpectedly.}

I read the release notes of api changes in 7.1 and i think CB Error code 10 is shipped in these updates. Actually, i was going to publish my app to app store but due to this issue, it will be delayed. Is there anyone having the same issue? Is there any workaroung to solve this issue?

Comment: You can install earlier versions of Xamarin.iOS to work around this for now (in your Xamarin Store account: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

You can install earlier versions of Xamarin.iOS to work around this for now (in your Xamarin Store account: store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads)